# Excel VBA macro for extracting column numbers from plots

Tags: excel, vba, plot, scatter-plot

I often make a lot of scatter plots (column j vs column i) in a single Worksheet. I want to export them as png/jpg files. Each plot would need a sensible file name. I have thought that the file name could be something like plot_[column i]_[column j].png.

How do I get the column (like C or AE) from each plot (or ActiveChart)? Then I can create a file name string to be fed in to the Export method. I am a complete beginner for VBA macros, but understand some Visual Basic.

Comment: Record a macro while changing a column; change its color or something. If you study that macro, you'll find how to find them in the object model.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract that information from the source data string using text functions. The source data is available using `.SeriesCollection`:

```
activesheet.chartobjects("Chart 1").chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
```

will return something like this:

```
"=SERIES(,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4,1)"
```

That contains the two columns you need, "A" and "B". You can extract them using text functions like `INSTR()`, `MID()`, and `LEFT()`. Here is an example using debug.print to output the columns. I'm assuming you already know how to export them since that was not included in your question.

```
Sub FindSourceColumns()
    Dim sourcedata, firstcolumn, secondcolumn As String, c as chartobject

    for each c in activesheet.chartobjects
        sourcedata = c.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
        firstcolumn = Mid(sourcedata, InStr(sourcedata, "!$") + 2, 5)
        firstcolumn = Left(firstcolumn, InStr(firstcolumn, "$") - 1)
        Debug.Print firstcolumn
        secondcolumn = Mid(sourcedata, InStr(InStr(sourcedata, "!$") + 2, sourcedata, "!$") + 2, 5)
        secondcolumn = Left(secondcolumn, InStr(secondcolumn, "$") - 1)
        Debug.Print secondcolumn
    next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this should work fine. Is it possible to go through all plots and do the same in a For loop?

And can macro code make different plots as ActiveChart in a loop and then I can write
sourcedata = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula ? Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: Rather than use activechart, I would declare a variable, loop using: for each c in activesheet.chartobjects. I'll update my answer.

Comment: When the plots have more complicated selections than just two small blocks in two columns, this does not work well. Like A5, A9:A12 vs D5, D9:D12 produces A as the firstcolumn as well as secondcolumn. Can you think of a nice way to handle this?

Comment: You could reverse the string and search backwards in it.